# Do not add extra newline before <head> and <body> tags with VSCode's autoformatter

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

VSCode's formatter automatically inserts a newline before `<head>` and `<body>` tags and also before the closing `</html>` tag by default. In the default settings the following lines exists:

```
// List of tags, comma separated, that should have an extra newline before them. 'null' defaults to "head, body, /html".
"html.format.extraLiners": null,
```

I tried setting `html.format.extraLiners` in the user settings to `""` and also to `"none"` but it didn't change anything.

This is what I get:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

This is what I want:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>    
</html>
```

Comment: for me setting `html.format.extraLiners` to `"none"` worked.
EDIT: nevermind, noticed your answer about plugin causing the issue just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the ["JS-CSS-HTML Formatter"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) extension installed, which was causing the problems. After uninstalling it, everything now works as expected.

Comment: Ugh, me too. Thanks for actually posting this, saved me a few hours of searching probably. Weird thing is, there's no setting in that extension to change that either.

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, the empty string is treated the same as null in this case. Probably because both the empty string and null are falsy in JS. Code might have implemented this setting's default with a truthy/falsy check rather than `=== null`.

`"none"` should work, though. A string consisting of a single space character works for me, too:

```
"html.format.extraLiners": " ",
```